# Cannot create localizable strings files copies in XCode4

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode4, localization

I have a "Resources/en.lproj/Localized.strings" file, with some key/value pairs in the format:
`"key"="value";`

I select this file and in File Inspector in the Utilities Pane I choose to add a new localization (es) pressing the '+' button in the Localization tab.

This action should create a new file "Resources/es.lproj/Localized.strings", but instead the original "Resources/en.lproj/Localized.strings" now displays a small triangle at the left ( as if it were a folder ) and holds inside two files Localized.strings (English) and Localized.strings (Spanish). No es.lproj directory created.
I have never read of this behavior even in references to this using XCode4.

What I'm missing?

Updated info:

I have checked the  app bundle installed in my iPhone Simulator and the folders are created there, with the corresponding files.
I don't know if this is the default way but is confusing to me since reading the documentation this is not what I understand.

Comment: Are you sure the file content syntax is correct? It seems the example you posted misses a double quote. It should be "key"="value";

Comment: It was a mistake writing the post. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Your could try this : Quit XCode, relaunch your project. Remove all localizations from your project properties (keeping the files when asked), add them back, remove es localization on your file, then add it back.